# Install Windows Sample port monitor localmon (Win7 32-bits) from VS2013 Update 4

Tags: windows, printing, driver, monitor, wdk

I downloaded the example for a port monitor including localmon (http://tinyurl.com/kg8bvt7).
It compiles in VS2013. I managed to add a driver package to the solution. And I setup a test PC using WDK 8.1 (wdktestsetup.exe). I can ping this test PC from my development PC.

However, if I go to the Properties page of my driver package and choose "Deployment" I enabled deployment (check mark), specified the target computer name by it's IP address, choose "Install and verify" and from the combobox I selected "Default Printer Driver Package Installation Task (possible reboot)", then I still get an error when I try to deploy.

I build for "Win7 Debug" configuration and "Win32" platform.

The error which I get is:
Error   1   error : Could not connect to the remote computer for deployment.    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\build\Win32\ImportAfter\DriverDeployment.targets    69  9   monitors
Error   2   error : Printer model name must be supplied for printer driver deployment.  The model name must be supplied on the DriverInstall->Deployment property page. C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\build\Win32\ImportAfter\DriverDeployment.targets    69  9   monitors

I searched on info for the second error ... and I found this help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn641620%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

In section "Configure driver solution for debugging and deployment" it states that you should be able to "Type the name of the driver in the Optional Arguments field". I do not see such an Optional Arguments field in my VS2013 ...

Any hints on what I could try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the deployment property page, under the "Install and Verify" option, there is a text box where you can add text. That's where you should supply the printer model name.

If you can't see that text box, you might want to resize the property page to increase its height. I seem to remember that there was an issue in WDK 8 where there would be no vertical scroll bar on that property page, even though there should be. I'm not 100% sure if it was fixed in WDK 8.1.